# Rate limiter for partticular API key is not working for request per second in nginx

Tags: nginx, api-key, rate-limiting

**Following is the Nginx configuration used for Rate Limiter**

I'm trying to set the rate limiter per second for each API key with the following configuration and I did the load testing with 400 parallel requests with 125 iterations in JMeter.

Output not returned as per the rate limiter set in the configuration

***Note: I have set the rate limiter per minute for each API ley as similar to the following configuration like "rate=3r/m". It worked***

But with the same configuration why it is not working requests per second is my worry.

Can someone help me out to find the reason for the requests per second rate limiter not working?

Thanks in advance

```
# Rate Limiter By Input API Key Header
limit_req_zone $http_api_key zone=api_key_header_rate_limit:10m rate=400r/s;

# API client Rate limiter - START

map $http_api_key $r1 {
    key1 "1";
    default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r1 zone=r1:10m rate=40r/s;

map $http_api_key $r2 {
    key2 "1";
    default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r2 zone=r2:10m rate=50r/s;

map $http_api_key $r3 {
        key3 "1";
        default "";
}

limit_req_zone $r3 zone=r3:20m rate=30r/s;

# API client Rate limiter - END


server {
        listen 443 ssl;
#   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/html;

    # Brotli Settings
        brotli on;
        brotli_comp_level 5;
        brotli_buffers 32 8k;
        brotli_min_length 100;
        brotli_static on;
        brotli_types image/jpeg image/bmp image/svg+xml text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon;

    # Rate Limiter Zone
#   limit_req zone=r1 burst=39 nodelay;
#   limit_req zone=r2 burst=49 nodelay;
    limit_req zone=r3 burst=29 nodelay;
    limit_req zone=api_key_header_rate_limit burst=399 nodelay;
    limit_req_status 429;

    # SSL
#   listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
#   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
#    ssl_session_timeout 4h;
#    ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate/api_ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional; # Set to "on" if you only allow authenticated requests

    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}


    location ^~ /main {
                alias /var/www/html/main/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @main_laravel;
                index index.php;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/main/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
                        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
                }
        }

        location @main_laravel {
                rewrite /main/(.*)$ /main/index.php?/$1 last;
        }


        location / {
#                index index.html;
                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: `400r/s` sounds like a massive load that's probably not easy to simulate… did you try with `1r/s`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried